# How to find the common factors of 2 numbers

Tags: python, list

Print the number of common factors of a and b.

input  > 10, 15

Output > 2

The common factors of 10, 15 are 1 and 5

My code

```
def print_factors(x,y):
l = []
for i in range(1, x + 1):
    if x % i == 0:
        l.append(i)
m = []
for i in range(1, y + 1):
    if y % i == 0:
        m.append(i)
print (list(set(l).intersection(m)))
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: ")) #10
num2 = int(input("Enter a number: ")) #15
print_factors(num1,num2)
```

Is there any better way to optimize, like list comprehension. or using zip module

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you could find the greatest common divisor of the two numbers (GCD, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), and then factorize that.

Comment: use intersection between print_factors(num1) and  print_factors(num2), then count the number of elements `set1.intersection(set2)`

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/intersection-function-python/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently GCD is there already, so the other answer could be modified as

```
from fractions import gcd
def cf(num1,num2):
    n=[]
    g=gcd(num1, num2)
    for i in range(1, g+1): 
        if g%i==0: 
            n.append(i)
    return n

print(cf(int(input("a:")),int(input("b:"))))
```

Then of course you can use the "trick" from prime-tests, and loop until the square root of the number only, as divisors come in pairs:

```
from fractions import gcd
from math import sqrt
def cf(num1,num2):
    n=[]
    g=gcd(num1, num2)
    for i in range(1, int(sqrt(g))+1):
        if g%i==0:
            n.append(i)
            if g!=i*i:
                n.append(int(g/i))
    return n

print(cf(int(input("a:")),int(input("b:"))))
```

Comment: Answer is accepted, but I got wrong answer if I am executing very very big numbers, then its taking too much time 4 seconds for 3000 digits. is there any alternate way?

Comment: @sim Could you share (perhaps in the question or on pastebin) some example number-pair with known output to expect?

Comment: in python 3.9+ `gcd` is now in the math library, and no longer in fractions. `from math import gcd`

Comment: @NickHumrich thanks! I think I leave the post as it is (it pre-dates Python 3.9 by more than a year after all), but upvoted the comment for visibility.

Comment: "4 seconds for 3000 digits": this is completely impossible. The square roots is 1500 digits long.

Answer (score 4):

to find the factors which are common for two numbers , do

```
def cf(num1,num2):
    n=[]
    for i in range(1, min(num1, num2)+1): 
        if num1%i==num2%i==0: 
            n.append(i)
    return n

print(cf(6,12))

>> output [1, 2, 3, 6]
```

edit: if you want the number of common factors

```
print(len(cf(6,12)))
>> output 4
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants the quantity of common divisors. Just add the count at the end.

Comment: Answer is accepted, but I got wrong answer if I am executing very very big numbers, then its taking too much time. is there any alternate way?

Comment: below answer have better memory management so accepting the below